# Include user_metadata and app_metadata in JWT using Auth0

Tags: angular, authentication, auth0

I am using Angular 2 and Auth0 for authentication on my web app. I am able to get the user profile using the following code:

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: 'MY-DOMAIN',
    clientID: 'MY-CLIENT-ID',
    callbackURL: 'MY-CALLBACK',
    responseType: 'token id_token'
});
```

Login:

```
public login(username: string, password: string): void {
    this.auth0.client.login({
      realm: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
      username,
      password
    }, (err: any, authResult: any) => {
      if (err) {
        alert('Error: ' + err.description);
        return;
      }
      if (authResult && authResult.idToken && authResult.accessToken) {
        this.setUser(authResult); <--- Here is where I get the profile
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
    });
}
```

Saving `token` on `localStorage` and getting the profile:

```
private setUser(authResult: any): void {
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);

    this.auth0.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, (error: any, profile: any) => {
      if (!error) {
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        this.userProfile = profile;
      }
    });
}
```

So this works, but the profile object I get doesn't include the user_metadata or the app_metadata configured on the Auth0 website. How can I include it?

Answer (score 5):

Deevz answer is correct, accept it so it is marked as such. I would like to expand on it, however. You have to add a new rule to your auth0 client. This is done in the 'Rules' section.

```
function (user, context, callback) {
    var namespace = 'unique-namespace';
    context.idToken[namespace + 'app_metadata'] = user.app_metadata;
    context.idToken[namespace + 'user_metadata'] = user.user_metadata;
    context.accessToken[namespace + 'app_metadata'] = user.app_metadata;
    context.accessToken[namespace + 'user_metadata'] = user.user_metadata;
    callback(null, user, context);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: For some reason, i had to provide an url as unique namespace for this to work. i.e.   `var namespace = 'https://unique-namespace.com/'`

Answer (score 3):

You could use an Auth0 Hook. Login to Auth0 and on the left side navigation pane choose "Hooks". Under "Client Credentials Exchange" create a new hook. In here you can add to the scopes that by default your app passes in to the Lock API. Adding the following line:

```
access_token.scope.push('user_profile');
```

I believe should include both user_metadata AND app_metadata.

You should be able to also specify this from the client itself without using a hook. If you check out [this link](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/sending-authentication-parameters#scope-string-) it should show you some extra options you can specify with regards to the scope parameter. This sample looks particularly useful:

```
var options = {  auth: {
params: {scope: 'openid email user_metadata app_metadata picture'},  }};
```